# How does this scam work (supposed fraud protection)

Tags: scams

I’m getting many calls recently fro m “the bank fraud department”, “visa fraud department”, “PayPal fraud department”, telling me they stopped someone from taking £600 to £1200 out of my bank account. Of course it’s fake, but I tried finding out what the actual scam is.

Unfortunately pressing 2 when they say “press 2 to talk to an adviser” never gets far. They hang up quickly. I suppose I have to act more like a doddery old man close to dementia for them to talk to me.

Does anyone know how this scam would be continuing in order to get to my money? It seems they have no idea who I am, what my bank is and so on. (I am just curious. Getting many calls that look like scams but there is no follow through at all).

Comment: There’s no way this isn’t a duplicate dozens of times over already.

Comment: I would assume that their goal is to get you to "confirm" a bunch of information (SSN, name, address, bank account number, etc.) so that they can either open new credit accounts in your name or generate a withdrawal against your account.  But it's impossible to know just from the initial "confidence" part of the scam-- they might try to convince you to give them $50,000 in a shoebox https://www.thecut.com/article/amazon-scam-call-ftc-arrest-warrants.html

Answer (score 5):

This is a type of Recovery Scam. Even if you haven't been a victim of a scam in the past, they hope that you will answer the call and freak out because "someone" charged your account/card for $600 or something. (Note, there usually isn't even a charge. All they have is your name and number, which is essentially public domain at this point...)

Usually they will have you confirm some minor personal information like name, phone number, birth date; either through the phone or a Google form. Then, once they have you involved they will either ask for more personal info (SSN) or ask you to login to your online banking so they can "block the fraud" and/or "refund" the money back to you. At this point they steal your login info through a keylogger, fake website, or after you enter it into their Google form. Then they just take your money.

These scammers send out messages/calls to thousands of people, but they can only talk to one at a time. I would guess you are right that once they figure out you're not a senior or other highly vulnerable person, they just move on to the next caller.

Comment: Here in the UK I have a 'landline' (fixed phone connection). My wife and I have cell phones. For some while now, the only calls that we get on the landline are those 'Bank security department' ones. There is a gullibility filter from the start. Even if I forget that my bank says 'we will never call you', 'bank security' - what bank? Why don't they name it? It can be fun to waste their time.